# Prevent session from stealing input events?

Tags: wayland, input, keyboard-event

I'm debugging Hyprland and unfortunately it blocks all your input at some stage of initiatlization blocking all input events. Unfortunately this is also the moment I am trying to debug from another session on the same machine. Is there any way to tell linux to prevent Hyprland from grabbing ALL input events?